# Is Monty's last name actually Reynolds?

Tags: names, firefly

I was looking at [IMDB](https://pro-labs.imdb.com/title/tt0579540?rf=cons_tt_contact&ref_=cons_tt_contact) today, and to my surprise, [Monty](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Monty)'s last name was listed as "Reynolds."

[image: Monty Reynolds?]

No other websites I could find gave him any last name. It would be very strange if he had the same last name as Captain Mal, as there is nothing to suggest they are related.

Is his last name actually Reynolds? If so, is he related to Mal? If not, is it known why IMDB states it is?

Comment: He's not named as Monty Reynolds in the [shooting script](http://home.earthlink.net/~rdmadden/webdocs/Firefly_transcript_TRASH.html) but that doesn't mean that they didn't give him a surname afterwards.

Comment: IMDB's an unsourced wiki, so what they say isn't necessarily accurate.

Comment: Probably someone got confused and assumed that our Mrs. Reynolds's husband must be Mr. Reynolds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The source for this rumour appears to be a [fan-transcript](http://www.browncoats.com/?ContentID=42e6e09c477ce) that appeared on the browncoats.com website and was subsequently removed. It then seems to have transferred to IMDB where it's propagated outwards.

All of the genuine sources I've seen (shooting scripts, autograph books, etc) simply refer to him as "Monty", no surname.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

It may have been listed as Reynolds in an early breakdown.
Don't recall it as such in the script.
Wish I could be of more help.

Franc Ross

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange. We always appreciate answers from people personally involved in the production!

Comment: OK, whoever downvoted this answer needs to reverse their downvote!

Comment: @Jonah - Simply because this user uses Franc Ross as their username doesn't mean that it's the real Franc Ross :-)

Comment: @Richard - The odds are strongly in favor of that being the case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You should probably state that you played the character in question.

Comment: Ummm... Have to say it's kind of amusing for me to imagine someone wanting to pretend to be an aging, out of work, character actor! Yeah it's me. And the beard's back!

Comment: Do  you have a Facebook account or something that could provide more evidence? (I'm confident that you are who you say you are, but some other users don't necessarily agree).